# Real time alert in JasperReport Server 4.5?

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am trying to implement a system which sends out email alerts based on certain changes in the database - for instance, if the revenue for a certain store drops below 50% of the 30-day average, we'd like to automatically generate an alert to the relevant decision makers, so they can check what's going on. (Fictional example, we don't have stores)

Does *JasperReportc Server 4.5* (or any other related tool) provide any functionality which could accomplish this? If not, is there any open-source solution which would be suitable? Ideally we'd like a user-friendly frontend to define the criteria and design the alert mails.

Or can it be possible at database level?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have to mention that Jasper is just a reporting tool. It does not send any email alerts or anything. All it can do is generate dynamic reports at different times.

Perhaps your application itself can use SMTP or IMAP to send emails. You can code the necessary conditions in your application itself.

You can use Jasper in your application when you want fast-building dynamic reporting solutions. It takes less time on Jasper to create a report than building it in the application. Also, Jasper can have your report exported in PDF or Excel format also without having to jack around with API files. Jasper also offers charts and other graphical reporting structures.